# Ember variable to keep track of current route

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

Is there a property or variable that can keep track of the current route?

Or is there a way to know which route I'm on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @GennadyDogaev I want to fire an action when route changes.

Comment: You can use ``didTransition`` [event](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition). If you need this for a few or all routes, you may create a mixin and extend your routes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any route you can use : `this.controllerFor('application').get('currentRouteName');`

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out!